# How do I create multicolor text in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Say I want to combine two different colors into one, how would I do that? Like this
http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/highlight-text-with-the-gradient-fill-effect-in-word/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a new document in Photoshop.

Write the text on the document open.

Double click on the text layer and a dialogue box will open.

You will find a gradient option. Select it .

You can then select any gradient available or play around with colors to create your own gradient.

You also have options like style,opacity and blend mode that will give you different effects.
[image]